# Cloud Filter API: How to let cloud-unaware apps delete files, but actually just dehydrate them?

Tags: winapi, cloud

I'm working with an app that routinely deletes some of the files it works on, as part of cleanups - otherwise it would read the whole folder structure it uses, which would take a lot of time. It's assumed that the files have been backed up somewhere, and can safely be deleted locally - one can always restore them if needed. Now, I'm trying to check if the Windows Cloud Filter API can help with that - but since the app knows nothing of clouds, and I can't have it rely the cleanup tasks to other apps, I need a sync provider to detect that the app is trying to delete a file, intercept the action, check if the file has been synced before, and then dehydrate it - and (most importantly) show it in the filesystem as DELETED from then on, so that the app thinks it has successfully removed the file, but for the deletion to not be performed in the cloud.

The app can't just see a lot of placeholders failing to rehydrate, as it would fail to function. Is it even possible to not show dehydrated files to apps?

Comment: Placeholders are files. Windows has no user-mode API to allow you as a developer to hide a file from an application using the Windows API. You can write a (mini) filter driver: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/ (this is what Cloud Filter API is)

Comment: I know they are files. And a completely clueless application will try to read them, and the Cloud Filter will (try to) rehydrate them. What I need is a way of telling the app: "those files are NOT available, do NOT try to read them, please don't make me move them to a different folder just to hide them from you".

Comment: At the risk of narrowing the question too much - the application in question is Lightroom. I have a rather substantial library of photos, which I'd like to cloudify (vaporize?) - but as soon as LR starts trying to find out which folders and files are available (it's perfectly happy to mark missing ones as just unavailable at the moment), it'll either rehydrate everything... or probably blow up on all the read-failures when the filter driver refuses to rehydrate.

Comment: (To be exact: ONE of the apps is Lightroom. The question would make it sound as if LR was deleting files routinely, which it does not. The other is just my own software.)

Comment: An application can determine using the API that a file is a placeholder, but if it doesn't and tries to read it (not all types of access will trigger hydration, only request for content) the system will hydrate them. The question is why does this app loads the files' content in the first place, and maybe ask the vendor to make that optional, etc.

Comment: @SimonMourier: it's just indexing whatever it can find.

I'm starting to suspect I'm barking up the wrong tree, and I should rather be implementing another solution, NOT using the "dehydration" mechanism at all, but rather a Git/SVN-like system tracking changes and deletions and only "committing" them manually.